# Cambiar la escala del eje x en python

Tags: python, lista, funciones

He programado una función que regresa una lista de valores numéricos, mi problema reside al graficar  la función los valores del eje `x` no son los que necesito. Ya he usado `np.arange` pero resulta que deben tener la misma dimensión ¿Cómo hago para que en vez de iniciar en 0 inicie en 2? muchas gracias.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(s,p):
    if s >= 2*k+1:
        val_fun = 0
        for j in range(1,k+1):
            valor = q*(p**(j-1))*fun(s-j,p)
            val_fun += valor
    elif s == k:
            val_fun = p**k
    elif (k+1 <= s <= 2*k):
            val_fun = q*(p**k)
    return val_fun    

def funval():
    #returnx = " "
    lista = []
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        termino = fun(i,p)
        lista.append(termino)
    #print(lista)
    return lista

while True:
    try:
        p = float(input("Probabilidad p: "))
        k = int(input("éxitos k: "))
        if 0 < p < 1:
            q = 1-p
            print("q sera ", q)
            n = int(input("n: "))
        else:
            print("p debe estar entre 0 y 1")
        if n < 0 or k < 0:
            print("n debe ser un entero positivo")
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("lo valores deben ser enteros... ")
        continue
    except:
        print("intenta de nuevo!")        
    print(funval())
    plt.xticks(range(10))
    plt.plot(funval(), 'ro')
    plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias @JohanC pero con el código que escribiste sale otra gráfica, aunque sí cambian  los valores del eje x. Tal vez se te ocurra otra idea?

Comment: @JohanC :( aun no funciona. De todas maneras mucha gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `plt.xticks(range(2, n+1))` los estarán en las mismas posiciones que en `funval()`.

`plt.plot(lista_x, lista_y, 'ro')` hace una gráfica con un valor de `lista_y` para cada valor de `lista_x`. Sin la `lista_x` `plt.plot` elige como `x` los valores `0,1,2,...`. Para que el primer valor de `lista_y` corresponde con `2` habría que dar una `lista_x` con los valores `2,3,4,...` es decir `range(2,n+1`.

Nota que el código solo funciona con `k = 1` o `k = 2`. Otros valores de `k` dan un valor indefinido para `fun(2,p)`. ¿Tal vez `s` podría empezar con `k`? Es decir, cambiando los `range(2,n+1)` por `range(k,n+1)` en los 3 sitios.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(s, p):
    if s >= 2*k+1:
        val_fun = 0
        for j in range(1,k+1):
            valor = q*(p**(j-1))*fun(s-j,p)
            val_fun += valor
    elif s == k:
            val_fun = p**k
    elif (k+1 <= s <= 2*k):
            val_fun = q*(p**k)
    return val_fun

def funval():
    lista = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        termino = fun(i, p)
        lista.append(termino)
    return lista

p = .2 # float(input("Probabilidad p: "))
k = 2 #  int(input("éxitos k: "))
if 0 < p < 1:
    q = 1-p
    print("q sera ", q)
    n = 20 # int(input("n: "))

plt.xticks(range(2, n+1))
plt.plot(range(2, n+1), funval(), 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image: gráfico resultante]

Comment: muchisimas gracias, bueno resulta que me di cuenta del error luego de publicar la pregunta, tienes toda la razón, si coloco k = 3 me arroja "local variable 'val_fun' referenced before assignment", según he leido es un problema de los valores de la variable, trataré de corregirlo. Te agradezco mucho.

Comment: Si eso soluciona la pregunta podrías considerar [marcar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) la respuesta.